# Big theta of $ \lceil{log(n+1)}\rceil $

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I am trying to calculate the big theta of $ \lceil{log(n+1)}\rceil $.

I derived the following inequality:

$ log(n+1) \le \lceil{log(n+1)}\rceil \le log(n+1) + 1 $

Based on the definition of big theta, a function $ f(n) \in \Theta({g(n))} $ iff $ \exists \  c_1,\ c_2 > 0 $ and a constant $k $ such that $ \forall n \ge k $, $ c_1\cdot g(n)\le f(n) \le c_2 \cdot g(n)$

This means that we must define the inequality in terms of multiplicative constants. However, I have no idea how to formulate such an equation. Could someone please advise me?

Comment: Every function is it's own big theta.

Comment: Is there a simplified form of the function like $ logn $ ?

Comment: Yes, the two functions are big thetas of one another. It's a nice exercise to show it directly using the definition of big theta. Good luck!

Comment: Is it possible to find the big theta without having to do trial and error? I intuitively guessed that the answer would be $ logn $

Comment: Experience really helps.

Comment: Your question is a very basic one. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599) which cover some fundamentals you seem to be missing in detail. Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific problems you encountered. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "the big-theta of a function", just as there is no such thing as "the number that's approximately equal to $\pi$." There are infinitely many functions $f$ such that $\log(n+1)=\Theta(f)$.

Comment: Ah! That's right. How do I obtain the most simplified $ \Theta(f) $?

Comment: @LanceHAOH Define "most simplified".

Answer (score 0):

> $ log(n+1) \le \lceil{log(n+1)}\rceil \le log(n+1) + 1 $
>
> Based on the definition of big theta, a function $ f(n) \in \Theta({g(n))} >$ iff $ \exists \  c_1,\ c_2 > 0 $ and a constant $k $ such that $ \forall >n \ge k $, $ c_1\cdot g(n)\le f(n) \le c_2 \cdot g(n)$
>
> This means that we must define the inequality in terms of multiplicative >constants.

Remark that

$ log_b n<log_b(n+1) \le \lceil{log_b(n+1)}\rceil \le log_b(n+1) + 1< 3\log_b n$

for $n>1$.